# Calendar does not show up with FullCalendar Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, calendar, fullcalendar

I just integrated FullCalendar into my Symfony project. I used this CalendarBundle [here](https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle) and the installation was ok. Then I followed the "Usage" part, it's pretty good, I see in my html source code on the navigator, this :

```
<div id="calendar-holder"></div>
```

I included also :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Symfony/web/bundles/adesignscalendar/css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Symfony/web/bundles/adesignscalendar/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Symfony/web/bundles/adesignscalendar/js/fullcalendar/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Symfony/web/bundles/adesignscalendar/js/calendar-settings.js"></script>
```

(source from my navigator, the links are ok)

But the calendar does not appear, do you know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you included the twig file ?

Comment: Do you have any js error? Are you sure about your script `src` starting with `/Symfony/`?

Comment: Thanks for answers, I had to follow the "Usage" tutorial also for the first bundle to setup JsRoutingBundle

Answer (score 0):

you need to install FOSJsRountingBundle 
-> https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

and don't forget to include :

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```